# Order of Footnote Marks On Single Page

Tags: footnotes

Is there an official (or standard) order for footnotes in a single page or article?

The first footnote is usually marked with a: * (asterisk).

The second with a # (hash mark).

I've seen the third marked with a triangle but I can't seem to figure out what it's called.

Is there a list of offical footnote marks based on order?

Comment: The order will be dictated by the style guide you are following. Footnote markers are not universal.

Comment: @Choster well that *was* the question...

Comment: @tchrist he didn't ask for the reason. Your question contains a link to the question that contains the order, I proposed that as the dupe.

Comment: I have no idea how SE determines what to include in the top banner suggesting duplicate questions. Anyway, both are relevant in their different ways.

Comment: great question!! but a duplicate